# cant install yarn package from github

Tags: javascript, npm, package, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install a package from GitHub with `yarn`.

I have done this thing a lot before, but I'm not success with this repo:

`https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX`

I already tried without luck:

```
yarn add git+https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX
yarn add git+https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX.git
yarn add https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX
yarn add https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX.git
yarn add https://coolwanglu@github.com/pdf2htmlEX
yarn add https://coolwanglu@github.com/pdf2htmlEX.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - if you want the entire package:

```
yarn add https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX.git
```

Secondly, what you have tried don't work because you have `<br>` at the end of the urls:

`yarn add git+https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX<br>` =>
 `yarn add git+https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX`

---

Yarn **can** add repos that does not have a `package.json` in contrary to what Samuell says. (It is npm that can't handle them - creating [premature close error](https://github.com/coryetzkorn/state-svg-defs/issues/1) ).

Comment: the <br> was sure just a wrong typing when i wrote the question here. i have checked this options before, and it's didnt worked, but now for somehow it's work! :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because that repository is not a package. Its missing package.json .

Comment: and if repo doesnt has package.json it says that i can't clone it to my project?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using npm to install it?

If you have npm, just do

```
npm i yarn
```